# Checkbox Filter for Search Result in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to create a query table with checkbox filter functionality. You can simply run the following code snippet to understand more easily.

When user ticks the checkboxes, the following table should be filtered accordingly.

Now, I have following questions:

1. How can I make all checkboxes are checked in default? (When user click "Search fruit", they can originally see all checkboxes are checked and all fruits are shown.) I tried to input `checked` attributed in the HTML, but it doesn't work.
2. How to bind selected checkboxes with the following table to have a filter functionality? I tried to use `v-on:click` on each checkbox, but it seems not working...

The following is the simple code snippet:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isSearched: false,
        searchList: [],
        data: [ 
            { "name": "apple", "color": "red" },
            { "name": "banana", "color": "yellow" },
            { "name": "strawberry", "color": "red" },
            { "name": "avocado", "color": "green" },
            { "name": "kiwi", "color": "green" },
        ],
        selected: []
    },
    computed: {
        colors() {
           let colors = [];
           this.searchList?.forEach(fruit => {
              if(colors.indexOf(fruit.color) === -1){
                  colors.push(fruit.color);
              }    
           });
         return colors;
           
        },
        selectAll: {
            get(){
                return this.colors.length == this.selected.length;
            },
            set(value){
                let selected = [];

                if (value) {
                    this.colors.forEach(color => {
                        selected.push(color);
                    });
                }

                this.selected = selected;
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        this.searchList = this.data;
        this.isSearched = true;
      }
    }
});
```

```css
table, td, th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<button @click="search">Search Fruit</button>
<br/><br/>
<div v-if="isSearched">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Filter</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                       v-model="selectAll"
                       />
            </th>
            <th align="left">All Color</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="color in colors">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                        v-model="selected" 
                        :value="color" 
                        checked/>
            </td>
            <td>{{ color }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="fruit in searchList">
            <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ fruit.color }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `checked` attribute does not work initially is [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage):

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked, or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the
> JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

Therefore `this.selected = [...this.colors];` is in `search` method in the following code snippet. Also, `searchList` is a computed property and `colors` computed property has been changed for filter.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isSearched: false,
    data: [{
        "name": "apple",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "name": "strawberry",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "name": "avocado",
        "color": "green"
      },
      {
        "name": "kiwi",
        "color": "green"
      },
    ],
    selected: []
  },
  computed: {
    colors() {
      let colors = [];
      this.data.forEach(fruit => {
        if (colors.indexOf(fruit.color) === -1) {
          colors.push(fruit.color);
        }
      });
      return colors;

    },
    selectAll: {
      get() {
        return this.colors.length == this.selected.length;
      },
      set(value) {
        let selected = [];

        if (value) {
          this.colors.forEach(color => {
            selected.push(color);
          });
        }

        this.selected = selected;
      }
    },
    searchList() {
      const filteredList = [];
      this.selected.forEach(color => {
        this.data.forEach(x => {
          if (x.color === color) {
            filteredList.push(x);
          }
        });
      });
      return filteredList;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.isSearched = true;
      
      this.selected = [...this.colors];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="search">Search Fruit</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <div v-if="isSearched">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Filter</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" />
        </th>
        <th align="left">All Color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="color in colors">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="color" />
        </td>
        <td>{{ color }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="fruit in searchList">
        <td>{{ fruit.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ fruit.color }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and the final code solution. Very understandable!